# Kubernetes - Installation of Jenkins with helm

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm and kubernetes. When trying to install jenkins with persistent volume and claim using helm. Getting the below error and the pod is not turning to running state. Kindly help.

When described the pod, getting the below. Without PVC and PV, the pod is running and jenkins is accessible via the UI.

```
Warning FailedMount 0s kubelet, fargate-ip-3-209-31-152.ap-south-1.compute.internal MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "jenkins-efs-pv" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "EFSID:/" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4fff4b36-08d2-4747-a9ec-cdddc2ac723d/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/jenkins-efs-pv/mount": mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t efs -o tls fs-0dee1bbe67a139006:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4fff4b36-08d2-4747-a9ec-cdddc2ac723d/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/jenkins-efs-pv/mount
Output: Could not start amazon-efs-mount-watchdog, unrecognized init system "bash"
b'mount.nfs4: Connection reset by peer'
```

Comment: If you add your yamls to the question, it would provide a clearer picture.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#create-a-persistent-volume